# Font in Android is changing/formatting the text

Tags: android, fonts, formatting

I'm having an issue where I'm using some EditText fields for users to enter information about them. One of the fields is an Age field where I use a Date Picker. The problem is that the EditText is formatting the text that is being sent to it.

For example if the text being set to the Age field is `10/01/2019` it actually displays something like this `1%1/2019`(except the 1/2 is shown as a fraction). It's taking the `0/0` and turning it into `%`, and `1/2` and turning it into a fraction.

I'm wondering if there is something in the font file I can change, something in the EditText or TextView I can set to ignore any formatting done by the font

Comment: did u specify inputType for the EditText?

Comment: Yes. It is set to none.

Comment: Yes, dont set it to none. Set it to the correct inputType u require e.g: email/password/phoneno.

Comment: Setting the input type to anything else does nothing as I am not allowing the user to type in the field. I'm setting the text to it from the output of a Date Picker. The input type has no use.

Comment: If you dont need to take input, then why are u using editTexts anyway. A simple textView should do.Also Try to format the output string  of the datepicker before(by logging maybe and see if everything works there)

Comment: I'm using the EditText b/c of the look and feel of the view. It still needs the underline, same focus changes, same padding/margins. Don't focus too much on that. The issue has unrelated to how I'm using the EditText.
Formatting the string before, during, and after using TextWatchers does nothing. The Font file itself is taking the text and formatting it when displaying.